# JQueryUI Sortable sortchange event across connected Sortables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to detect when the order of a sortable changes. I need this to fire the change event regardless of where the sorted item comes from.

However, it appears there might be a defect in ui.sortable that does not fire the event when dragging from one connected sortable to another.

Consider:

1. User drags an item from Sortable#A to over to Sortable#B but does not yet drop it. **Change Event Fires on Sortable#A**.
2. User then drags the item within Sortable#A changing the sort order. **NOTHING Fires**
   Example:  http://screencast.com/t/rW4xj485OEc

In contrast, when a user starts a sort from within the same Sortable#A the Change Event fires EACH time on Sortable#A.
http://screencast.com/t/uirpg1E5nA

First off, this seems like a defect in ui.sortable. Second, does anyone have a suggestion on how I can get my cake and eat it too? I'm comfortable with forking ui.sortable if need be.

Comment: I guess change doesn't occur on the connected list, because as long as you haven't moved it, the item is still considered part of the first sortable's list. Have you tried the `over` event? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: over only fires on the initial hover, which event is really already captured by the Change event. There are a number of things I need to do during ALL changes to sortables order. I think you are right that maybe the item is still considered part of the original sortable. However, I don't agree that that makes any sense. The ChangeEvent should fire when a change in order or number happens in a sortable.

Answer (score 0):

The change event indeed fires only once on the connected sortable, but it does fire on the original sortable every time the position changes on the connected sortable.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orig/r4Phf/2/)

Depending on exactly what you're trying to acheive, you can use a combination of events to get the info you need:

- `start` tells you the `$(ui.item)`'s current sortable.
- `over` tells you the connected sortable (`$(this)`) which the item was dragged into.
- `change` tells you that the item moved inside the sortable last `over`-ed or `start`-ed.

So store an item's current sortable in its data, and modify it on `start` & `over`, and maybe delete it on `stop`.

I do agree with you though, it should've been easier.